# How do I iterate an output data from an array in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a daily weather app and i'm having issues trying to figure out how to output the data into cards for all seven days. its currently only outputting the last day. I know that its because if am setting it to `$("#card__days").html(` but im not sure how to add onto the current html.

Is there also any easier way to output this information? I feel like I did way too much for a simple task. Thank you

```
    function updateDaily(data) {
        Object.keys(data.daily.data).forEach(function (i) {
            // call to find what the day is.
            let date = calculateDay(data.daily.data[i].time);

            console.log(data.daily.data[i]);
            let iteration = i;
            let high = data.daily.data[i].temperatureHigh;
            let low = data.daily.data[i].temperatureLow;

            let feels = data.daily.data[i].apparentTemperature;
            let desc = data.daily.data[i].summary;
            let icon = data.daily.data[i].icon;
            let skycons = new Skycons({ color: "#3e606f" });

            $("#card__days").html(`
            <div class="card__daily">
                <h2 id="daily__date"${iteration}">${date}</h2>
                <canvas src="" alt="icon" class="icon" id="daily__icon${iteration}"></canvas>
                <div class="degrees">
                    <h3 id="daily__high${iteration}" class="temp">${high}&#8457; / ${low}&#8457;</h3>
                </div>

                <h3 id="daily__desc${iteration}">${desc}</h3>
            </div>
            `);
            skycons.add(
                document.getElementById("daily__icon" + i),
                icon
            );
            skycons.play();


        });
    }
```

EDIT: Here is what it currently looks like and some data from the API.

[Current Visual Output](http://prntscr.com/mfuci6)

[Some data from Object](https://pastebin.com/UYBB3vaU)

Comment: What's your desired output HTML structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make all seven cards appear, use [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append) instead:

```
$("#card_days").append(/* Your card HTML */);
```

Comment: Is there any way I can simplify that html in javascript or is that probably the best I can do? but this works Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You only see the last card because in each iteration the for loop *overwrites* the html with the latest ${iteration} data, instead  of creating a new piece of data and a new html element. To fix this:

- You could use the $("#card_days").append method, from the other comment in this thread, but personally in a similar situation I used:
- $("#card_days").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html) method, it will insert the code you give it as an html parameter just before the closing tag of the element you selected.

As a side note, I only used insertAdjacentHTML because I needed the user to be able to create and delete these html elements, so their amount could not be predefined. In your case, it seems like you know you need exactly 7 elements. If this is the case, I would suggest to stick with html and css, and the only usage of JS would be to update a placeholder text with the newly-fetched data. Hard-coding in this case seems a bit more error-proof :)